# Main activity preview don't match app

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't see my app preview. The app runs and looks normal, but I see a white screen. I also can't see elements that I have dragged and dropped.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you post your layout code and activity code please

Comment: Move your emulator out of the way - do you see a red exclamation mark in the top-right corner of the layout preview?

Comment: You are not using your layouts properly. If you are using constraint layout, then you have to set constraints on your views.

Comment: I changed my api version and it works. Thanks for answearing.

Comment: @rolp Good to hear. Woud you mind posting *how* you solved your issue (i.e. what API version you changed to) and post it as an answer? Just so this post can help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I repleced orginal code in build.gradle (Module: app) by this one `dependencies {
    debugImplementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}` then I changed my API version from 28 to 22.